# Calling Swift function from Objective-C in a swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

There is a **swift project** in which I have an objective-C file. I would like to call a Swift class function from Objective-C file

What is the best way to do this ? I have done it using `NSNotification` but wanted to know if there is a better way to do this.

**Test-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "ObjectiveC.h"
```

**ClassA.swift**

```
@objc class ClassA {

    func f1() {

    }
}
```

**ObjectiveC.h**

```
void objC_f1()
```

**ObjectiveC.m**

```
void objC_f1() {

    //Create an instance of ClassA and call function f1
}
```

**Conclusion**

- There was some trouble caused because I was had a testcase scheme.
- When I created a new project without a testcase scheme, it worked ok.
- Pls Note - The -Swift.h generated but will not be listed in the project navigator
- This answers my question - [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: It appears your example is not real code? The file names do not match the contents. Specifically, what is "Test-Bridging-Header.h". Is this a file you created manually? What are you importing at the top of ObjectiveC.h and .m?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: @MikeD that is just opposite of this question.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple doc [Apple Doc Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html):

> Importing Swift into Objective-C
>
> When you import Swift code into Objective-C, you rely on an
>   Xcode-generated header file to expose those files to Objective-C. This
>   automatically generated file is an Objective-C header that declares
>   the Swift interfaces in your target. It can be thought of as an
>   umbrella header for your Swift code. The name of this header is your
>   product module name followed by adding "-Swift.h"

For example if your product name is MyApplication, you just have to import the generated file `MyApplication-Swift.h`.

Comment: This is a swift project and as stated in the question a bridge file is added. Yet it doesn't work.

Comment: If i understand you question, you want to call swift functions from Objective-C no?

Comment: Yes but this is a swift project. Is there a way to create an objective C bridge. If so could you post sample code.

Comment: You use the the bridge file to call Objective-C code from swift code but my response above show you how to make available Swift code inside Objective-C code. A `MyApplication-Swift.h` file is automatically generated(the name depend on your project/module name) created and you can use it.

Comment: -Swift.h is not getting generated. How do I generate it ? Instead only Test-Bridging-Header.h was generated. But in build settings I am able to see the entry Test-Swift.h under "Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name"

Comment: What's the name of your application?

Comment: I just realised that Test-Swift.h was getting generated but it was not listed in the list of files in the left panel (file browser panel)

Comment: Yes, it's not listed!